# Using Custom Javascript and pHp to send email to myself when a user clicks on an input button but only works on Chrome, IE, and Micorosft Edge

Tags: php, jquery, email, server

So I am using jQuery and pHp together to send an email to myself whenever a user clicks on the update button of their Ultimate Member form. However, the email only sends when a user is using Chrome, IE, and Microsoft Edge. When using Safari and Firefox, it doesn't work. I am using a click event listener to send JSON to my pHp file. The JSON was originally an object that was created by a function that checks for the differences between two different objects. These objects were created using DOM traversal. In that pHp file is a mail() function that sends me the aforementioned JSON to my email. I've tried replicating the process on a test site and noticed that when I didnt add the jQuery that comes before my click listener, emails do indeed get sent from Safari and Firefox. However, if I add the jQuery code and THEN remove it and test again it won't send! It's as if my server gets permanently rejected. Here is my JS code:
(function($){

```
$(document).ready(function(){

console.log('mailajax is enqueued, showing on firefox');

var ogArray = new Array(),
    newArray = new Array(),
    dropOgArray = new Array(),
    dropNewArray = new Array(),
    difference,
    username = $('.um-name').find('a').attr('title');


function diffObject(a, b) {
  return Object.keys(a).reduce(function(map, k) {
    if (a[k] !== b[k]) map[k] = b[k];
    return map;
  }, {});
}

$('input.um-form-field').each(function() {

    var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text();
    var $value = $(this).val();

    ogArray[$key] = $value;

});

console.log(ogArray);

setTimeout(function(){

$('span.select2-chosen').each(function() {

    var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text();
    var $value = $(this).text();

    // console.log($value);

    dropOgArray[$key] = $value;

});

console.log(dropOgArray);

},1000);



$('input.um-form-field').on('keyup', function(){
    $('form').find('input.um-form-field').each(function() {

        var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text();
        var $value = $(this).val();

        newArray[$key] = $value;

    });

    console.log(newArray);

    console.log(diffObject(ogArray, newArray));

    difference = diffObject(ogArray, newArray);
});

$('select.um-form-field').on('change', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('form').find('span.select2-chosen').each(function() {

            var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text();
            var $value = $(this).text();

            dropNewArray[$key] = $value;

        });

        console.log(diffObject(dropOgArray, dropNewArray));

        dropDifference = diffObject(dropOgArray, dropNewArray);
    }, 1000);


});


$('.um-profile-body .um-button').on('click', function(e) {

    $('form').on('submit', function(){

        console.log('form was sent successfully');
        var ajaxurl = 'http://www.reformeducators.org/wp-content/themes/NATE/admin-ajax.php';
            stringDifference = JSON.stringify(difference);
            stringDropDifference = JSON.stringify(dropDifference);
            stringUsername = String(username);


        $.post(ajaxurl, {'Name': stringUsername, 'Changes Made': stringDifference, 'Drop Down Menu Changes': stringDropDifference});


    });


});


});

})(jQuery);
```

And here is my pHp code:

```
<?php

$message = "User Information has been changed\r\n";
$message .= print_r($_POST, true);


$to = "testing@domain.com";
$subject = "User information has been changed!";
$headers = "From: ";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 




?>
```

I think this might be a server issue, but if anyone has any experience doing something like this, I would really appreciate some feedback or help.

Comment: Bro it's just "php", but +1 for effort

Comment: Thats exactly the type of help I was looking for thanks -____-

Comment: Sorry couldn't resist. Do you know how to use the browser console? We need to know what kind of error you're getting.

Comment: I would also add that since this only works with some browsers, it must be a client-side issue.

Comment: Nothing on Firefox's and Safari's console, besides the console.logs thats in my code. :/ @TheDeadMedic

Comment: Can I ask what is your confirmation that "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error, anywhere? Or are you just not getting the email? (do not rely on email delivery for testing if the script works, use the error log/post back a response in your script).

Comment: Well I know that the script works because I receive the emails when I use Chrome or Internet Explorer to submit the email. But it just doesn't send to my email when I try submitting from Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Ok longshot, but I spotted at least one thing - you're attaching to the `submit` event for the form, but you're not disabling the default behaviour (i.e. a regular 'ol form submit). Maybe Safari/FF handles it too soon and prevents/aborts your AJAX request.  Try [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38e86086424039db472295f1b5b27cc4) and let me know how you get on.

Comment: I can't prevent those events from happening, they're tied up with a plugin that's necessary for the site :/ But I tried the code anyways and it didn't work. I do that you're on to something about the form, submit event. I tried disabling it and it did send me an email from Safari. But it was a one time thing lol @deadmedic

Comment: `preventDefault` only stops the native browser event - other event handlers will still work. Bro, if you say you did it and it worked... well... that's what the problem was.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out about 10 minutes ago, just trying to figure out how to maximize the code. Haha thanks @TheDeadMedic

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that on Safari and Firefox, the page would refresh before the email got sent out. As a workaround I just created another button that the user has to click on before clicking on the actual button that updates their profile information. The click event handler on that first button is being used to send out the information to the php file now. It solved the problem and now I'm getting emails no matter what browser the user is updating their profile from!

Heres's the javascript:

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){

// console.log('mailajax is enqueued, showing on firefox');

setTimeout(function(){

if($('html').hasClass('user-section')){
    // console.log('this is a user page');
    $('input.um-button').hide();
    $('.um-profile .um-col-alt .um-left.um-half').prepend('<a id="custom-update-btn">Approve Changes</a>');
}


var ogArray = new Array(),
    newArray = new Array(),
    dropOgArray = new Array(),
    dropNewArray = new Array(),
    difference,
    username = String($('.um-name').find('a').attr('title'));

function diffObject(a, b) {
  return Object.keys(a).reduce(function(map, k) {
    if (a[k] !== b[k]) map[k] = b[k];
    return map;
  }, {});
}

$('input.um-form-field').each(function() {

    var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text(),
        $value = $(this).val();

    ogArray[$key] = $value;

});

$('span.select2-chosen').each(function() {

    var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text(),
        $value = $(this).text();


    dropOgArray[$key] = $value;

});



$('input.um-form-field').on('keyup', function(){
    $('form').find('input.um-form-field').each(function() {

        var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text(),
            $value = $(this).val();

        newArray[$key] = $value;

    });

});

$('select.um-form-field').on('change', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('form').find('span.select2-chosen').each(function() {

            var $key = $(this).closest('.um-field').find('label').text(),
                $value = $(this).text();

            dropNewArray[$key] = $value;

        });

        // console.log(diffObject(dropOgArray, dropNewArray));


    }, 1000);


});



$('a#custom-update-btn').on('click', function(e){
    // console.log('update btn has been clicked on');

    var ajaxurl = 'http://www.reformeducators.org/wp-content/themes/NATE/admin-ajax.php',
                  stringDifference = JSON.stringify(diffObject(ogArray, newArray)),
                stringDropDifference = JSON.stringify(diffObject(dropOgArray, dropNewArray));       
    $.post(ajaxurl, { 'Name': username, 'Changes Made': stringDifference, 'Drop Menu Changes': stringDropDifference});

    $('a#custom-update-btn').hide();
    $('.um-profile-body .um-button').show();
});

}, 1000);







});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Don't forget you can 'accept' this answer by clicking the check mark on the left of it. That way, it won't come up in our 'unanswered questions' list anymore :) Good on you for solving it!